# what should i add in model initialization in torch.nn?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, discriminator, generative-adversarial-network

what should be added in model initialization?  do the LeakyReLU and Dropout have learnable  parameters in 
the given model like weights of the Linear layer ?

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        self.label_embedding = nn.Embedding(opt.n_classes, opt.n_classes)
        self.lin= nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True)
        print( self.lin.parameters)
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(opt.n_classes + int(np.prod(img_shape)), 512),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.Dropout(0.4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, 512),
            nn.Dropout(0.4),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(512, 1),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model initialization looks fine to me, just write the forward function to call the operations defined in `__init__` and you should be all set.

As for your second question on learnable parameters, ReLU and Leaky ReLU are simply activation functions that perform a predefined operation. For instance, ReLU is defined as `max(0,x)`, so it simply outputs the max value of the two inputs. While neither ReLU nor Leaky ReLU have learnable parameters, Leaky ReLU does have a hyperparameter, which is the `negative_slope`, as from its function definition `max(0, x) + negative_slope * min(0,x)`.

Comment: yeah,it is activation function but why we are adding this in model parameters we could have applied it in forward method.my question is what is difference between applying activation in model initialization and in forward method ?

Comment: @SunilSharmaMT19AI004 `nn.LeakyReLU` is just a light wrapper class around `nn.functional.leaky_relu`. For layers with no learnable parameters there's no meaningful difference between using the module version and the functional version. Take a look at the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#LeakyReLU) and you can see this is the case.